# What's the proper (or best) way to size text to fit a rectangle?

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I'm drawing in a canvas using Android (Java) and been doing it as shown below where size can be width or height and SIZE is he restraint. Is there a better way?

```
    Rect rec = new Rect();
    for (textSize = 4; textSize < 100; textSize++) {
        paint.setTextSize(textSize);
        paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length() - 1, rec);
        if (rec.size() > SIZE)
            break;
    }
    paint.setTextSize(textSize - 1);
    paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), rec);
```

Comment: start loop from 50, step 50 if more then divide step by 2  else *2 etc until step == 1   - it is more fast

Comment: Thanks! Great idea...I was hoping there was a canned method but apparently not the case.